# JavaScript performance on hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, angularjs

I'm writing a hybrid app with HTML5, JavaScript and CSS for Android 4.0+ and iOS 7.0+. I was wondering: **does JavaScript consumes much memory of the smartphone?** Basically my script will: parse objects, handle events, Ajax calls, update the view, etc. I was considering about use jQuery o Angular.js too.

I'm focusing on performance and smooth experience.

Thanks!

Comment: apples and oranges... and entirely dependant on how you use each.

Comment: in both cases you are able to kill the device if you use them incorrectly. Use the one you know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Angular JS uses Jquery for some of its operations, and uses its own built in version if none is declared. I would suggest reading the documentation for a full grasp.

Answer (score 2):

As Ari Lerner writes about AngularJS in ng-book, "When we mix Angular into the flow, it extends this normal browser flow to create an Angular context. The Angular context refers specifically to code that runs inside the Angular event loop, referred to as the $digest loop." This is good for updating the view with a JavaScript library.

Both AngularJS and jQuery are extremely efficient, and can be used together to meet the needs listed above.

In my opinion, the optimal JavaScript library for mobile is [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com).